# App Crashes when I'm trying to assign attributedText to UITextView

Tags: ios, swift, crash, uitextview

```
libc++abi: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'NSTextContentStorage: Inconsistent element cache state. Elements for range {0, 36} are not cached while trying to insert'
terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

The app crashes with the above error.

I'm extracting the attributed string from the html, and then assigning it to textView. Here's the code which I'm using whenever there is a call to my method updateView.

```
func displayTextView(with text: String) {
    text.attributedStringFromHTML{ attrText in
        self.textView.attributedText = attrText
    } 
}

public func attributedStringFromHTML(completionBlock: @escaping (NSAttributedString?)->()) {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            if let attributedString = try? NSAttributedString(data: customUtfData, options: [
                .documentType: NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html,
                .characterEncoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue,],
                documentAttributes: nil) {
                    completionBlock(attributedString)
            } else {
                print("Unable to create attributed string from html string: \(self)")
                completionBlock(nil)
            }
        }
    }

PS: Here customUtfData, is customised to replace unknown tags and is working fine.
```

App, is crashing intermittently. It's working fine for most of the cases.
Can someone guide me here?

Thanks!!

Comment: You need to [edit] your question to include all relevant code in the form of a [mcve] in order to make the question on-topic.

Comment: Ok @DávidPásztor, editing it right away.